# How do i get the field "name" from this json format array?

Tags: react-native, mobile, axios

i have done an axios get method to fetch child objects from database.

the response comes as json array to i pushed in child array using setChild state.

question is, How do i get specific "name" field from this json array?

```
Array [
  Object {
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "652d629910f73ec732aa7912",
    "bod": "2023-10-09T22:00:00.000Z",
    "createdAt": "2023-10-16T16:19:37.855Z",
    "fathersName": "Abdurrahman Abulifa",
    "name": "ahmedan",
  },
]
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON.